# Starred expression inside square brackets

Tags: python, numpy, syntax

It seems that starred expressions can not be used inside square brackets the way they are inside parentheses:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.ones((3, 4))
>>> x[:, *(None, None), :]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x[:, *(None, None), :]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

though one would expect the latter to output the same as

```
>>> x[(slice(None), *(None, None), slice(None))]
array([[[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]],


       [[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]],


       [[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]]])
```

Do you know any good reason why this is not allowed, and if there are plans for supporting it in the next Python releases?

Comment: The `[*]` would only be used in `numpy`. Regular python indexing only allows one value. `(*)` occurs in many places, sometimes without the ()

Comment: Regular python indexes actually allow multiple inputs. They are gathered in a `tuple` that is passed to the container's `__getitem__` method. Other libraries such as `pandas`, `pytorch`, etc., also use the `numpy` multi-index style so I wouldn't say it is only a `numpy`-related issue! And indeed starred expressions can be used without parentheses, but still wouldn't it make sense to call `container[*items]` similarly to `function(*args)`?

Comment: That `__getitem__` tuple was added because `numpy` needed it.  None of the builtin Python objects use it.  I've `pandas` and `pytorch` as `numpy` derivatives.  You can even write your own class that takes advantage of the feature.  I raise the point just to argue that `[*]` would not be of much use to core Python.

Comment: Tuple * expansion is used in cases where the () are implied.  In fact it's the comma that defines a tuple not the ().  However I don't know enough of formal syntax to say whether the use of `*` in unpacking is the same as its use in function arguments and tuples.  I suspect it's all handled by the same branch.

Comment: Actually, `*` does work in lists, `[*abc] = 1,2,3`; `[*abc]`.  But the indexing brackets don't create a list.  It may be brainstorm this issue here, it really belongs in a PEP or Python development board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for how to do that, the answer probably is `x[:, None, None, :]`. But maybe you have a tuple that contains `nones = (None, None)`, in which case you can do: `x[:, nones[0], nones[1], :]`. But I agree this would be nicer to have `x[:, *nones, :]` being valid.

On the question, why isn't it possible, we can have a look at the [Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html#full-grammar-specification) to see why this doesn't work:

```py
trailer: '(' [arglist] ')' | '[' subscriptlist ']' | '.' NAME
subscriptlist: subscript (',' subscript)* [',']
subscript: test | [test] ':' [test] [sliceop]
sliceop: ':' [test]
```

If you follow the longest and most promising grammar branch from `test`, searching for a `'*'` literal (I don't present the whole subtree because most other branches stop very early) : `test -> or_test -> and_test -> comparison -> xor_expr -> and_expr -> shift_expr -> arith_expr`.

Note that the rule we are searching for is this one

```
star_expr: '*' expr
```

Let's see if we can find it from here (`arith_expr`):

```py
arith_expr: term (('+'|'-') term)*
term: factor (('*'|'@'|'/'|'%'|'//') factor)*
factor: ('+'|'-'|'~') factor | power
power: atom_expr ['**' factor]
atom_expr: ['await'] atom trailer*
```

Remember, `trailer` is where we started from, so we already know there is nothing that leads to `star_expr` down here, and `atom` closes all these different paths:

```py
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |
       '[' [testlist_comp] ']' |
       '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' |
       NAME | NUMBER | STRING+ | '...' | 'None' | 'True' | 'False')
```

Basically you should only be allowed to use as a `subscriptlist` any of the expressions we saw down the branch (`test -> ... -> arith_expr -> ... -> atom`) or any one from `NAME | NUMBER | STRING+ | '...' | 'None' | 'True' | 'False'`).

There are lot of branches that I didn't went through here. For most of them you can understand why just by looking at the rules' name. On the other hand it's probably not useless to double check.

For example when reading expression `test`:

```py
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
```

We can see that `['if' or_test 'else' test]` closes the path (as we are looking for `* something`). On the other hand, I could have included `lambdef` as this is perfectly valid for our quest, I simply ignored such paths because they close right after we explore them (applying a single rule invalidades `*...`), in this case (as you might have guessed):

```py
lambdef: 'lambda' [varargslist] ':' test
```

We see a `'lambda'` here, it's not an expression that starts with `'*'` so the path closes. Interestingly, that implies that `x[lambda e: e]` is perfectly valid syntax (I wouldn't have guessed and I never saw it but it makes sense).

In the end, we didn't saw a single leading `*` expression in the process, thus there should be no ambiguity in what you propose (unless I missed one combination of rules). Maybe that would make sense to ask to someone who've actually worked on this to check if there is a good reason for not having this outside potential grammar ambiguities.